# Cannot run program - 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is not installed

Tags: 12.04, application-development, python, quickly

I am trying to make a python app that basically views a web page with QUICKLY on Ubuntu 12.04.

When I do `sudo quickly run` in terminal, I always get this error:

```
(saikoroubuntu:5283): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema
'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is not installed
```

What seems to be the issue?

Here is my code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python


import gtk
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://shifat.tk/apps/saikoro/ios"))
web.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm basically using the code I found on Stackoverflow: ["How to make a simple cross-platform webbrowser with Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566720/how-to-make-a-simple-cross-platform-webbrowser-with-python)

Comment: You probably want to remove the `import gtk`. Gtk is an alternative to Qt, so you wouldn't normally use both in one application. Also, you probably don't need `sudo` to run your app.

Comment: running the code code you posted (with a different url...) with `import gtk` and with or without `sudo` works for me. I guess you have to give more information. Are you really using the standard Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 8):

quite later, but try to install `gsettings-desktop-schemas`.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain how you would do that, what this would do, the risks etc.

Comment: For posterity, this solution worked for me. Just run "sudo apt-get install gsettings-desktop-schemas".

Comment: For whatever reason I needed to do this (i.e. reinstall this package) after a system upgrade on Arch to make GNOME work at all, so thank you!